# The system cannot find the file specified in java

Tags: java, file

I am making a program that opens and reads a file. 
This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileRead{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            File file = new File("hello.txt");
            System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
            FileInputStream ft = new FileInputStream(file);

            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(ft);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strline;

            while((strline = br.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(strline);
            }
            in.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

but when I run, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\Workspace\FileRead\hello.txt
Error: hello.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

my `FileRead.java` and `hello.txt` where in the same directory that can be found in:

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\Workspace\FileRead
```

I'm wondering what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream if you want to read text, its more confusing than useful.

Comment: in windows system sometimes what happens is..
you keep show file extension feature off and you try naming file as xyz.txt
it will create a file having name xyz.txt.txt and hence your code will not be able to find that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have copied your code and it runs fine.

I suspect you are simply having some problem in the actual file name of hello.txt, or you are running in a wrong directory.  Consider verifying by the method suggested by @Eng.Fouad

Comment: thanks Adrian, my hello.txt is in the another directory the /src, thanks guys for all you answers

Comment: I had the same problem, I changed directory `cd Desktop\MyProject\` and then It was fixed

Answer (score 66):

Try to list all files' names in the directory by calling:

```
File file = new File(".");
for(String fileNames : file.list()) System.out.println(fileNames);
```

and see if you will find your files in the list.

Comment: This is late but why do we need a `.` inside `new File` params @JoelMin?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I'd assume it's like the unix `.`, where it means the current directory

Comment: This answer is helpful to debug the issue and find root cause actually.

Answer (score 9):

You need to give the absolute pathname to where the file exists.

```
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Workspace\\FileRead\\hello.txt");
```

Answer (score 3):

How are you running the program?

It's not the java file that is being ran but rather the .class file that is created by compiling the java code. You will either need to specify the absolute path like user1420750 says or a relative path to your `System.getProperty("user.dir")` directory. This should be the working directory or the directory you ran the java command from.

Comment: This is the approach that helped me. Found what is actually my user.dir and from there try to make my program find a properties file, in my case I just added "/src" in order to locate the file.

Answer (score 3):

In your IDE right click on the file you want to read and choose "copy path"
then paste it into your code.

Note that windows hides the file extension so if you create a text file "myfile.txt" it might be actually saved as "myfile.txt.txt"

Answer (score 3):

Generally, just stating the name of file inside the File constructor means that the file is located in the same directory as the java file. However, when using IDEs like NetBeans and Eclipse i.e. not the case you have to save the file in the project folder directory. So I think checking that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you run a jar, your Main class itself becomes args[0] and your filename comes immediately after.

I had the same issue: I could locate my file when provided the absolute path from eclipse (because I was referring to the file as args[0]). Yet when I run the same from jar, it was trying to locate my main class - which is when I got the idea that I should be reading my file from args[1].

Answer (score 1):

First Create folder same as path which you Specified. after then create File

```
File dir = new File("C:\\USER\\Semple_file\\");
File file = new File("C:\\USER\\Semple_file\\abc.txt");

if(!file.exists())
{
    dir.mkdir();
    file.createNewFile();
    System.out.println("File,Folder Created.);
}
```