# Can't initialize file array without error handling, but then It won't let me use it.

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I am new to Java. In my course, we must input an existing file using the Scanner object.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputFile {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner inFile;

public class InputFile {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("artwork_info.txt"));
    int quantity = new Integer(inFile.nextLine());
  }
}
```

That gives "me unreported exception FileNotFoundException".

```
try {
  inFile = new Scanner(new File("info.txt"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.out.println("Try Again");
}
int quantity = new Integer(inFile.nextLine());
```

Then I get an error that inFile might not be initialized.

I walked through the steps from [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553042/the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-in-java#_=_) and the file names are right and still the same problems. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First way: add `throws`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
```

Second way: put `int quantity = ...` line (and subsequent statements) inside the `try` block:

```
try {
  inFile = new Scanner(new File("info.txt"));
  int quantity = new Integer(inFile.nextLine());
  // ...
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  // ...
}
```

The first way is preferable to the second way, if you're not actually going to do anything "interesting" with the exception, because it doesn't indent the code using the `inFile` unnecessarily.

A third way:

```
Scanner inFile;
try {
  inFile = new Scanner(new File("info.txt"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.out.println("Try Again");
  return;
}

int quantity = new Integer(inFile.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are directly accessing the file, that means your Java file must working on the same location where **artwork_info.txt** is places, if you put this file on a nested directory then you will get **FileNotFoundException**.
so if your **txt** file is inside a folder you have to provide the folder name >>

You have used as

```
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("artwork_info.txt"));
```

Replace it as

```
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("YourFolderPath\artwork_info.txt"));
```

In your case you get **FileNotFoundException** that mean your program not able to detect the file you have provide, that mean its clear there is something problem in **FileName** or **ExtentionName** or **NestedDirectory**.

Try to fix this you may get rid of it, Gud Luck!!